# object.forEach in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach

In one of the articles I found a code statement like this.

```
this.http.post(`/rate`, {id: talk.id, yourRating: rating}).forEach(() => {});
```

I understand the `forEach` has been applied to an object but what are the empty `()` and `{}` doing inside the `forEach`? What does it mean?

Comment: `()=>{}` is a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which takes no arguments and returns nothing.  This seems to be a basic JavaScript syntax question. Is there something more specific you need?

Comment: Based on the `this.http.post()` it looks like you may be using Angular and RxJS. You wouldn't usually (if ever) use `forEach()` on an `Observable<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this for the sake of an answer, but hopefully you've already got some ideas from the comments.

`() => {}` is an empty function. It does nothing. You'd fully utilize the `forEach` method by placing something inside those curly braces, so:

```
this.http.post(`/rate`, {id: talk.id, yourRating: rating}).forEach((someItem) => {
     console.log(someItem);
     // or something else!
});
```

To break that down even further:

1. `this.http.post(...)` - fires off an HTTP request, returns the result most likely in the form of an array (which has a foreach method)
2. `.forEach` - accepts a callback that is fired on each iteration (`['1', '2', '3']` => `callback(1); callback(2); callback(3);`)
3. `() => {}` - that's your callback. The specific syntax is [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You might be more familiar with a standard `function() { ... }` which would work here as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The 2nd parameter in the http.post method is the body where we send in the parameters to the backend right? So why would one apply a blank for each to it?. The for each should be applied to the result that is received back like in the success or failure. Or is it attached to the success event of the call internally? Please correct me if I am wrong as I am just starting with this.

Comment: My bad i just noticed the foreach is applied on the response of the http.post call. Got it.

Comment: @Subbu Yeah! It can be really confusing to have everything in a single line, a lot of times I'll put a new line between the end of `this.http.post` and the beginning of `.forEach` just so it's visually more obvious what's happening. Glad you figured it out! :)